# Always add to last Listitem position and maintain it

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, sharedpreferences

On my app the user can enter the hourly update of the amount of something. For example, at hour one they would enter 100 and add it to the last. They would navigate to a different activity and then come back to that when the next hour comes and enter in 200.

This seems to be working fine although after maybe one or two entries the list seems to get a mind of its own and start to randomly sort the list.

Screenshot of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Achieve]

Screenshot of what is happening (usually after the 3rd entry):
[image]

As you can see the 3rd one has taken position of the 2nd one and this happens randomly and they go to different positions.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.processing);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", MODE_PRIVATE );

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btnShippersCompleted = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4) ;
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);

    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listView.setAdapter(null);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.apply();
        }
    });


    handler = new Handler() ;

    ListElementsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ListElements));

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Processing.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            ListElementsArrayList
    );

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    btnShippersCompleted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            shippersCompleted = textView.getText().toString();
            Hour = sharedPreferences.getInt("Hour", 1);
            ListElementsArrayList.add(shippersCompleted + "- Hour " + Hour++);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //Set the values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.addAll(ListElementsArrayList);
    editor.putStringSet("list", set);
    editor.putInt("Hour", Hour);
    editor.apply();
    }


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Set<String> set = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("list", null);
    if(set != null) {
        ListElementsArrayList.addAll(set);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Processing.this, "No records have been saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

can anyone help me so that each time it adds to the last position and when I return to that activity again it maintains that position.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Always use List if you want to retain insertion order(can have duplicate elements), Use HashSet when order doesn't matters and also you don't want duplicate data.

Change you onPause() and onResume() with List instead of HashSet

```
     @Override
        protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Set the values
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        //save in LinkedHashSet instead of HashSet
        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        set.addAll(ListElementsArrayList);
        editor.putStringSet("list", set);
        editor.putInt("Hour", Hour);
        editor.apply();
        }
           @Override
     public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //get saved list and set if for display
        Set<String> set = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("list", null);
        if(set != null) {
            ListElementsArrayList.addAll(set);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Processing.this, "No records have been saved!", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Aaron, I wrote a sorting answer, but DhaRmvEEr's answer is more suited, so I deleted mine. You also need to delete a redundant `setAdapter` in the button click listener, as it was already set once in the onCreate method.

Comment: getting some errors here guys. it says that List<String> set = sharedPreferences.getString("list", null); is incompatible type. but when I cast it and run it, it gives exception.

Comment: also in editor.putStringSet("list", set); it is red line error under set

Comment: @EugeneKartoyev.. what was your sorting code? this answer is making me cast and it is breaking my app.

Comment: @Aaron since I'm just learning android so I was not aware that sharedPreferences will accept an instance of Set<String>.. So you need to change you code according to that.. just few lines like the places where you were using HashSet<String> before now we need to use LinkedHashSet<String> and it will retain insertion order for you.. Note: It will not allow duplicate elements.. You can refer changed code.. but since I have typed it on notepad so let me know if you face any compilation error.

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh your code copied and pasted in fine. But when I ran it and entered a few test data the order was still not retaining. for example, order was hour 1, hour 3, hour 2

Comment: Please debug or print data inside set and list just to check which line actually breaking this.. because as per code this should work.. only possibility is  sharedPreferences.getStringSet("list", null); may not returning exact sequence if yes you can find other solution to get inserted order.

Answer (score 0):

Use only lists, not sets. The problem is exactly about the HashSet that changes the order.

To resolve the problem with saving your list to prefs, you can convert your list to String and save it. In onResume, you can read the String back and convert it to Array back.

```
// Use some delimiter that will surely not be used in your array elements
private static final DELIMITER="//";
private String convertToString(ArrayList<String> list) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String delim = "";
        for (String s : list)
        {
            sb.append(delim);
            sb.append(s);
            delim = DELIMITER;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

 private ArrayList<String> convertToArray(String string) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(string.split(DELIMITER)));
        return list;
    }
```

So, when you save your array, save it as

```
 prefEditor.putString("my_array", convertToArray(myList));
```

retrieve it back as

```
 myArray = convertArrayToString(prefs.getString("my_array", "");
```

Adapt your variable names correspondingly.